# Convert any random html object to string in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to render an html object in **React**. I need to take html, pass it to **React** as a `String` and have it render there. I am uncertain how to proceed.

The html object can be anything like

```
<p>Hey man&nbsp;</p>
<p>nlkansnsa</p>
<p>as</p>
<p><strong>asasas</strong></p>
<p><strong>knla</strong></p>
<p><br></p>
<ul>
  <li><strong>point 1&nbsp;</strong></li>
  <li><strong>point 2</strong></li>
  <li><strong>point 3&nbsp;</strong></li>
</ul>
<p><br></p>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "html object" what you've pasted there is an HTML document which would most likely be represented with a string in javascript. Are you asking how you would render this in React, given the HTML as a string?

Comment: yes i want to render this in react

Comment: This is a very loose question. You should be more precise about the specific problem that you have, not ask general questions. You should include code that you have written and indicate what your desired output would be from that code, were it working in the manner that you intended.

Comment: Will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to `render` string that contains `html` elements, like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<div>hello</div>" }}></div>
```

You can pass any variable also that contain that string, like this:

```
let htmlString = "<div>hello</div>";

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:  htmlString}}></div>
```

Check the **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)**.

Check this example:

```js
let string = "<p>Hey man&nbsp;</p><p>nlkansnsa</p><p>as</p><p><strong>asasas</strong></p><p><strong>knla</strong></p><p><br></p><ul><li><strong>point 1&nbsp;</strong></li><li><strong>point 2</strong></li><li><strong>point 3&nbsp;</strong></li></ul><p><br></p>";

var App = () => {

   return(
      <div>
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<div>hello</div>" }}></div>
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: string }}></div>
      </div>
   )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```